# Kotlin generic function return type does not conform to declared nullability

Tags: kotlin, generic-function

```
fun <T: Any?> function(input: T): T = input
fun function2() {
    val n = function(1)!!
}
```

Since `T` is declared as nullable, I expected the output to be nullable as well, but Lint produces `Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type Int` warning.
Changing the output type signature to `T?` makes the warning go away.

Why does the output type not conform to the declaried nullability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T: Any?` does not mean "`T` is nullable". It constrains the type parameter `T` to be a subtype of `Any?`. Nullable types, *as well as non-nullable types* satisfy this constraint. In general, if `B` is a subtype of `A`, then `A`, `B`, `A?`, and `B?` are all subtypes of `A?`.

When you do

```
val n = function(1)
```

The type parameter `T` is inferred to be `Int`, which is a non-nullable type that satisfies the constraint `: Any?`. The function is declared to return a `T`, so in this case it returns an `Int`. There are no problems here, and `!!` is unnecessary.

Compare that to:

```
val n = function<Int?>(1)
```

where you explicitly say that `T` should be `Int?`, which is a nullable type (that also satisfy the constraint of `: Any`). In this case the function returns `Int?`, and `!!` can be added without a warning.

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: @yaugenka That completely changes the question, doesn't it? You also didn't show a [mcve]. Specifically, What is `Call`? I would suggest that you post a new question instead.

Comment: @yaugenka If I have to _guess_, it would because `response.body()` returns a `T?`.

Comment: All right. Have popsted that as a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/70634164/5360898

Answer (score 2):

Declaring `T` as `<T: Any?>` doesn't mean that `T` is/has to be nullable. It only means `T` **can** be nullable, but doesn't have to be.

If you pass `1` which is `Int`, then `T` becomes `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

T is deduced as Int which is non-nullable

Answer (score 0):

that's because

```
function(1) --> 1 is not nullable and no need for assertion
```