# Kotlin class generic type infered as nullable

Tags: kotlin, generic-function

A generic class for holding network request result

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any?> {
    data class Success<out T : Any?>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val message: String, val exception: Exception? = null) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

A generic function for encapsulating network result into `Result`.
It is called from a repository and passes a retrofit2 api call as an input parameter

```
suspend fun <T: Any?> request(method: Call<T>): Result<T> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val response = method.awaitResponse()   // Retrofit2 Call
            if (response.isSuccessful)
                Result.Success(response.body())
            else
                response.getErrorResult()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Error(e.message.orEmpty(), e)
        }
    }
    // Type mismatch.
    // Required: Result<T>
    // Found: Result<T?>
}
```

It is called like this

```
interface Webservice {
    @GET("data")
    fun getData(): Call<Data>   // Retrofit2
}

suspend fun getData(): Result<Data> {
    return request(webservice.getData())
}
```

Why does it infer the result as type `T?` but not `T`?

Comment: I'm assuming `response.body()` is [this](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#body--)?

Comment: Yes. Have updated the question with a call example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
Result.Success(response.body())
```

[`body`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#body--) is marked with `Nullable`, so when ported to Kotlin, `response.body()` returns a `T?`, rather than `T`. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) for how this works.

Therefore, the type parameter for `Result.Success` is inferred to be `T?`, and so the expression above creates a `Result<T?>`. Note that the `T` in `Result<T?>` refers to the type parameter of `request`.

Comment: `since you have checked isSuccessful, body shouldn't be null`, it can be null, when the server returns OK with null value, but this does not matter here. I'm just confumed, why does it make it 'T?' while 'T' already allows a nullable value?

Comment: @yaugenka You might be confused because these two `T`s are not the same. `T` (the type parameter for `Result.Success`) allows a nullable type, so it is inferred to be a nullable `T` (the type parameter for `request`), aka `T?`.

Comment: @yaugenka Or are you asking why does `T?` exist at all, when `T: Any?`? Well, as I have said in my previous answer, both nullable and non-nullable types satisfy `T: Any?`, so `T?` represents a `T` that is definitely nullable, and that is what the designers of the Retrofit API wanted `body` to return.

Comment: I think, I have understood it now. If the `request` is called with a method which returns a non-nullable type, like in the example provided, then `T` will be inferred as non-nullable and that would contradict the nullability of `body`. Thanks!